# How to get all tags with content from an element using PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

Is it possible to get all HTML elements (children) with content using PHP (DOMDocument class)? I just can't get the results. Let say I only know that I will have `<td>` tag but don't know what tags would be inside `<td>`
Example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$el = "<td><a href='http://google.hr'>test1</a><div>Test2</div></td>";
$doc->loadHTML($el);
$doc->getElementsByTagName("td")->item(0)->nodeValue /* I only get plain text */
```

EDIT: No JavaScript like solution

Comment: how to get attributes, with values? It looks like the only "clean" way its to use library like PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser which I know exists.

Comment: Did you see the accepted answer which iterates/walks over every node recursively? Once you are on a node, you can do whatever you want, including attributes. If that's not what you want, can you edit with an example of what you want to get out of this?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all element information:

```
$html = "<td><a href='http://google.hr'>test1</a><div>Test2</div></td>";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element ){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_R($element);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

To get Attribute information use like:

```
$p = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
if ($p->hasAttributes()) {
  foreach ($p->attributes as $attr) {
    $name = $attr->nodeName;
    $value = $attr->nodeValue;
    echo "Attribute '$name' :: '$value'<br />";
  }
}
```

Comment: where is href attribute?

Comment: href is not a tag.

Comment: @Slit I have updated answer to get attribute name.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like the only way to do it is to iterate and check element by elemet. Nothing like in JavaScript innerHTML